# Eclipse autocomplete with $this->test

Tags: php, eclipse, phpdoc

How can we have autocomplete on property when this one isn't define in the same php file.

for example, with ZF, in the controller we can do

```
$this->view->voiture = new My_Voiture();
```

and in the view, we have a variable $this->voiture, but how can i have the autocomplete on it ?

i try `/* @var $this->voiture My_voiture */` and no result...

for the moment, my answer is to do in the view

```
/* @var $voiture My_Voiture */
$voiture = $this->voiture;
```

but i don't like it. Have you better ?

Comment: There's no way for Eclipse to guarantee that the line in the controller will always be called before the line in the view (maybe the view is called from somewhere else entirely), so no auto-complete will help. Ultimately, you should document the fields in the views script anyway, so you might as well do it with your current method.

Answer (score 0):

Documenting the original variable in its original source is actually the best way to go, I think.  All other usages of your view in other files should inherit the autocompletion just by documenting it at its one source.

In order to get the autocompletion that I would expect, I would do these things:

- In the My_Voiture class, make sure you have docblocks for your variables and your methods.  This isn't technically necessary for the autocompletion itself, but it will allow the autocompletion popups to contain much more info that just variables and methods.
- In the My_View class, where $voiture is first declared (not used), I would place the @var docblock that identifies its type as My_Voiture.  This should be enough to make any usage of its $voiture variable inherit the properties of My_Voiture.
- In the My_Controller class, where $view is first declared (not used), I would place the @var docblock that identifies its type as My_View.  This should be enough to make any usage of its $view variable inherit the properties of My_View.

Now, in your code file where you are expecting autocompletion on $this->view->voiture -- if it has nothing in it that indicates that $this is a My_Controller object, then Eclipse has nowhere to start when it tries to identify $this (and then all of its properties).  I think I've seen some MVC code before where this is prevalent, due to much "dynamic" properties relying on "variable variables" like $$foo.

Comment: But eclipse don't make the link between view and controller.

Comment: A nasty side effects of view scripts being included as a piece of code instead of being classes.